# Most 5 set matches won in a row

Tags: tennis, records, atp

[Alexander Zverev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Zverev) won 3 consecutive 5 set matches in [2018 Roland Garros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2018_French_Open_%E2%80%93_Men%27s_Singles#Section_8) before losing to Dominic Thiem in the quarterfinals.

What is the record for most consecutive 5 set match wins in the history of tennis in the modern era? Please list the players and the tournament(s) the wins spanned.

Comment: Do you mean consecutive matches that went to 5 sets or consecutive 5 set match wins across GS.

Comment: I mean consecutive games that went 5 sets and were won by a player

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are four players that won four 5-set matches at Grand Slam tournaments, but neither of them in four consecutive matches:

- [Albert Costa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albert_Costa) ([2003 French Open](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2003_French_Open_%E2%80%93_Men%27s_Singles))
- [Nicolás Lapentti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicol%C3%A1s_Lapentti) ([1999 Australian Open](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1999_Australian_Open_%E2%80%93_Men%27s_Singles))
- [Todd Martin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Todd_Martin) ([1994 Wimbledon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1994_Wimbledon_Championships_%E2%80%93_Men%27s_Singles))
- [Steve Denton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steve_Denton) ([1981 Australian Open](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1981_Australian_Open_%E2%80%93_Men%27s_Singles))

If we count Olympic Games and not only Grand Slams, [Goran Ivanišević](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goran_Ivani%C5%A1evi%C4%87) won **four consecutive 5-set matches** at [1992 Olympics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tennis_at_the_1992_Summer_Olympics), before losing in semifinals to Marc Rosset (who went on to win the tournament).

**Wins in three consecutive matches that went to five sets**

- Australian Open

  - [Colin Dibley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colin_Dibley) in [1979](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1979_Australian_Open_%E2%80%93_Men%27s_Singles#Section_4)
  - [Steve Denton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steve_Denton) in [1981](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1981_Australian_Open_%E2%80%93_Men%27s_Singles) - Denton won the first three rounds in five-set matches. He won one more 5-set battle in the semifinals, but eventually lost in the final to Johan Kriek.
  - [Nicolás Lapentti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicol%C3%A1s_Lapentti) in [1999](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1999_Australian_Open_%E2%80%93_Men%27s_Singles#Finals); he won the first three rounds in five-set matches. Then he won another five-setter in the quarterfinals before losing to Thomas Enqvist in the semifinals.
  - [Thomas Johansson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Johansson) in [2005](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2005_Australian_Open_%E2%80%93_Men%27s_Singles#Section_4)
  - [Dominik Hrbatý](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominik_Hrbat%C3%BD) in [2006](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2006_Australian_Open_%E2%80%93_Men%27s_Singles#Section_2) - he won the first three rounds in five set matches, and then lost to Davydenko again in five sets.
  - [Adrian Mannarino](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adrian_Mannarino) in [2024](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2024_Australian_Open_%E2%80%93_Men%27s_singles)
- French Open

  - [Rolf Gehring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolf_Gehring) in [1978](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1978_French_Open_%E2%80%93_Men%27s_Singles)
  - [Eliot Teltscher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eliot_Teltscher) in [1979](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1979_French_Open_%E2%80%93_Men%27s_Singles#Section_4)
  - [Richard Krajicek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Krajicek) in [1993](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1993_French_Open_%E2%80%93_Men%27s_Singles#Finals)
  - [Gustavo Kuerten](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gustavo_Kuerten) in [1997](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1997_French_Open_%E2%80%93_Men%27s_Singles#Finals)
  - [Albert Costa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albert_Costa) in [2003](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2003_French_Open_%E2%80%93_Men%27s_Singles#Section_2); He won the first three rounds in five-set matches. Then he won yet another five-setter in quartefinals.
  - [Gaël Monfils](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ga%C3%ABl_Monfils) in [2006](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2006_French_Open_%E2%80%93_Men%27s_Singles#Section_7)
  - [Tommy Robredo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tommy_Robredo) in [2013](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2013_French_Open_%E2%80%93_Men%27s_Singles#Section_5)
  - [Alexander Zverev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Zverev) in [2018](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2018_French_Open_%E2%80%93_Men%27s_Singles#Section_8)
  - [Juan Pablo Varillas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juan_Pablo_Varillas) in [2023](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2023_French_Open_%E2%80%93_Men%27s_singles#Section_3)
- US Open

  - [Roscoe Tanner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roscoe_Tanner) in [1974](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1974_US_Open_%E2%80%93_Men%27s_Singles#Section_4)
  - [Dan Goldie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dan_Goldie) in [1986](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1986_US_Open_%E2%80%93_Men%27s_Singles#Section_3)
  - [Stefan Edberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan_Edberg) in [1992](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1992_US_Open_%E2%80%93_Men%27s_Singles). He won the tournament after five-set wins in semifinals, quarterfinals and fourth round.
  - [Wayne Ferreira](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayne_Ferreira) in [1993](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1993_US_Open_%E2%80%93_Men%27s_Singles#Section_7)
  - [Robby Ginepri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robby_Ginepri) in [2005](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2005_US_Open_%E2%80%93_Men%27s_Singles#Finals) - he won five-set matches in third and fourth round and in quarterfinals, before losing to Agassi in semifinals, again in five sets.
  - [Andre Agassi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andre_Agassi) in [2007](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2005_US_Open_%E2%80%93_Men%27s_Singles#Finals)
  - [Marcel Granollers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marcel_Granollers) in [2013](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2013_US_Open_%E2%80%93_Men%27s_Singles#Section_1)
- Wimbledon

  - [Jan Kodeš](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jan_Kode%C5%A1) in [1974](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1974_Wimbledon_Championships_%E2%80%93_Men%27s_Singles#Section_5); after three consecutive wins in five-set matches, he lost in quarterfinals to the eventual champion Connors, again in five sets.
  - [Russell Simpson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell_Simpson_(tennis)) in [1982](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1982_Wimbledon_Championships_%E2%80%93_Men%27s_Singles#Section_5)
  - [Alex Rădulescu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alex_R%C4%83dulescu) in [1996](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1996_Wimbledon_Championships_%E2%80%93_Men%27s_Singles#Section_8)
  - [Jason Stoltenberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jason_Stoltenberg) in [1998](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1998_Wimbledon_Championships_%E2%80%93_Men%27s_Singles#Section_2)
  - [Todd Martin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Todd_Martin) in [1994](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1994_Wimbledon_Championships_%E2%80%93_Men%27s_Singles#Finals) - with the exception of second round all his wins were in five sets, then he lost in semifinals to Pete Sampras.
  - [Janko Tipsarević](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Janko_Tipsarevi%C4%87) in [2007](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2007_Wimbledon_Championships_%E2%80%93_Men%27s_Singles#Section_2)
  - [Ernests Gulbis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ernests_Gulbis) in [2018](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2018_Wimbledon_Championships_%E2%80%93_Men%27s_Singles#Section_6)

**Sources**

- [The History Books Await Zverev](https://www.atpworldtour.com/en/news/zverev-roland-garros-2018-sunday-reaction) ([Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20190328153322/https://www.atptour.com/en/news/zverev-roland-garros-2018-sunday-reaction))
- [Five Set Matches at One Slam](http://www.tennis28.com/slams/five_sets_tournament.html) ([Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20180606120210/http://www.tennis28.com/slams/five_sets_tournament.html))
- [French Open: Knackt Zverev diesen Grand-Slam-Rekord?](http://www.insideout-tennis.de/knackt-zverev-grand-slam-rekord/) ([Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20180613055925/http://www.insideout-tennis.de/knackt-zverev-grand-slam-rekord/))
- [2018 Roland Garros – Day Ten Men’s Preview](http://www.tennispanorama.com/archives/62446) ([Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20180606120745/http://www.tennispanorama.com/archives/62446))

Comment: The answer is [community wiki](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/community-wiki/info) - feel free to add further improvements, sources, corrections, etc.

Comment: Love the community wiki answers you out up @Martin. They're great +1